# Change a static variable "dynamically" in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the below class where I set what language should be the "running" language on the website.
Right now I just in/out comment the language I want to have chosen before running/debugging my project.

I would like to be able to change the language dynamically while my website is running.
 How would you go about doing that (I would like to avoid solving it using a session parameter or a cookie that will run run out on some date in the future)

```
public class LanguageCodes
{
    public const string DenmarkCode = "DK";
    public const string SwedenCode = "SE";
}

public class LanguageFactory
{
    public static readonly string CurrentLanguage =
     LanguageCodes.DenmarkCode; 
   //LanguageCodes.SwedenCode;

    public static AbstractLanguage Current {
        get {
            switch (CurrentLanguage)
            {
                case LanguageCodes.DenmarkCode: return new LanguageDK();
                case LanguageCodes.SwedenCode: return new LanguageSE();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's already available through .NET itself, in the request thread's CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture properties. It's *those* properties that control which resource strings are loaded, how numbers and dates are formatted and parsed.

Comment: On other note, if you don't use Session or Cookie, the change to the static variable will apply to all users.

Comment: Why would you want to change the Website?  The client should specify the language in the request or get the default culture from the client.

Comment: Check Rick Strahl's [Auto Selecting Cultures for Localization in ASP.NET](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/mar/27/auto-selecting-cultures-for-localization-in-aspnet). It shows how you can set the language using various techniques, either automatically or from a user's profile.

Comment: [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in the docs explains how these things work in ASP.NET Core. The concepts are similar to ASP.NET WebForms or MVC so it's worth reading

Answer (score 1):

In your current implementation you cannot do that.

`const` is compile known variable and it cannot be edited even with reflections.

The only way of doing that is to write a program that can edit its own source code and recompile itself. I think you do not want to do that.

However you can play with

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");`

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.7.2)

If you want to keep your implementation change `const` to `static`

```
   public class LanguageCodes
    {
        public static string DenmarkCode = "DK";
        public static string SwedenCode = "SE";
    }

   ///

    public static string CurrentLanguage
```

Comment: But all of my language properties are stored in my own classes - I am not using the custom .net language classes. I am simply just doing this:

       public class LanguageDK : AbstractLanguage
       { 
       public override string BeskedSkalUdfyldes => "Besked skal udfyldes.";

So I guess I cannot use Thred.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture 

or ?

Comment: So change the type to "Static" without a const.

Comment: @NickDeveloper why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? You *can't* modify the language unless you change the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture settings. No matter what your classes do, strings will be formatted using the thread's CurrentCulture. UI strings will be generated using CurrentUICulture. That's covered in the documentation of each ASP.NET stack - Webforms, MVC, ASP.NET Core

Comment: @Sebastian506563 if I understood it correctly, Op's not trying to modify `DenmarkCode` or `SwedenCode` (after all, they are constant and not related to current ui language), but `CurrentLanguage` (which was declared as `readonly` so a similar problem occurs)

Comment: Is the only solution to convert my classes into native .net language/culture classes? or can I fix it by removing const? Will I then be able to change what the CurrentLanguage variable points to dynamically ?

Comment: Really what I would like to do is change what CurrentLanguage points to - while my website is running.

Comment: @Magnetron you are right. He also need to remove readonly. Otherwise he should play with native culture depending on his needs.

Answer (score 0):

I actually saw this way today that might be helpful:

```
 private const string someString="my name is {0}";

 string newString = string.Format(someString, "Didi");
```

Comment: Can you explain (edit your answer) how this helps the OP with the language issue?